# Pantheon-mail won't archive Gmail

Tags: pantheon-mail

Thank you for your help! I've linked my Gmail account with Pantheon-Mail on the latest Elementary OS. Emails download and I can send them no problem. My problem is that when I press A or archive, nothing happens! The emails don't delete or archive.

I've tried pressing the respective icons as well, to no avail.

My system info is:
elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
Linux 4.13.0-32-generic
GTK+ 3.18.9

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try killing your running Pantheon Mail instance and launching it with the `--debug` option set:

```
pkill pantheon-mail
pantheon-mail --debug
```

If you're having the same issue as me, then you should see Pantheon Mail is trying to use the wrong IMAP folders for archiving/trashing mails, and this breaks the UI commands you're trying to use.
The Online Accounts dialog doesn't offer a "Gmail" provider option (even though Pantheon Mail has [code for handling that explicitly](https://github.com/elementary/mail/tree/bcb67ba5d59582d6d0fdc6b1ebeb50e72fdfb618/src/engine/imap-engine/gmail)) and thus the configuration for Pantheon Mail ends up being wrong.

I've found a temporary fix -- I haven't yet found a way to persist this configuration change as it is automatically regenerated.
Again, make sure Pantheon Mail is not running:

```
pkill pantheon-mail
```

Then open the `~/.local/share/pantheon-mail/YOURACCOUNT@gmail.com/geary.ini` file, change `service_type` from `OTHER` to `GMAIL`, and save.

Launch Pantheon Mail again and enjoy your archiving/deletion... until the next login.

Answer (score 0):

This might also be a language issue: I could not delete mails until I changed the configuration in geary.ini fom

```
trash_folder=Trash;
```

to

```
trash_folder=Papierkorb;
```

as I'm using a German Gmail account. After that a delete was possible...