# pantheon email "connection error unable to validate"

Tags: pantheon-mail

pantheon mail is not working with only my yahoo account although it was working before but for some reason after i made `apt update` this mail only stopped working.

I tried to make SMTP & IMAP settings manually as described [from yahoo site themselves](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/sln4075.html) but to no avail.

this issue is more described in this [github opened issue](https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/466)

I have Thunderbird email and it did not face any issues that pantheon was facing.

Comment: I know this is not the answer. I have my own mail server and I just removed this app and installed Thunderbird. Geary is a 3rd party app or is treated this way and there is a workaround for Google mail to let it work with this app. So try to look for something like how to make Gmail work in Geary or Pantheon/Elementary Mail app. Maybe it will help you. It looks like this mail app is not authenticating properly by default.

Comment: I have the same problem, and it appears into ubuntu 18.04 Geary also. Yesterday I did upgrade the ubuntu into 20.04 and Geary works again with Yahoo!. It looks like yahoo ignores the older version that is the present now into Elementary OS Hera

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution: [Pantheon-mail won't archive Gmail](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14622/pantheon-mail-wont-archive-gmail)

I did not test it. Just try to change the service name to Yahoo.

I do not use this mail app and removed it completely. I can recommend Thunderbird or Evolution.